# Disable bootstrap button does not work with submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic "contact us" form that asks for some basic information and has a submit button at the bottom.  When the user clicks submit the form will be submitted to itself and the fields validated.  If no errors, a routine is called that generates an email.

I want the button to be disabled and also have the label changed to "Sending..." when the user clicks it.

I was able to use the jQuery bootstrap calls to change the button label and then disable it... great!  But as soon as I add a form submission, the changes to the button no longer occur?

I am not sure if it is the order things are done in the code or some other reason related to the submit?  Here are the pertinent code bits (note all in PHP):

```
<html>
<form id='jkform'>
F_hidden_field("action",$G['action']);

... // bunch of forms fields

    //--- Submit Button ---
    echo "<div class='form-group'>";
        echo "<div class='col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9'>";
        echo "<button type='button' id='sendButton' class='btn btn-primary' autocomplete='off' data-complete-text='Sending...' onclick=\"$(this).prop('disabled',true);$(this).button('complete');J_action('send_email');\">";
        echo "Send Message";
        echo "</button>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
...
</form>
</html>
```

Additionally, the JS function that simply submits the form is the following:

```
function J_action(the_action) {
    document.jkform.action.value = the_action;
    document.jkform.submit();
}
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why the submit would squash the changes to the button?  I hope I am just missing something obvious.

Thanks.

---

Followup 5/26/16 - 5:12pm PT

PRE NOTE:  I was just about to post the lengthly followup below, when I cross-browser tested this and discovered that my original code works perfectly as-is in Chrome, IE11 and Firefox, but **not** in Safari.  I think this may actually be either a bootstrap & Safari compatibility issue or a Safari rendering issue (less likely).  Still leaves me with an issue to deal with, but at least proves I am not crazy!  For proof of concept, here was my original followup...

---

ORIGINAL FOLLOWUP POSTING:

Thanks for the feedback.  I still think something is fishy here.

One **important** thing I may not have mentioned that is when the original page calls itself from the submit, it is only calling a PHP edit check function and if it passes, a PHP function that generates an email and finally a redirect to a "thank you page."  What is important here is that the original script **never posts anything to the client** until the redirect to the thank-you page.  In my understanding of client server in HTTP, that should leave all form fields and elements in whatever state they were in until some new HTML is pushed to the client.

To prove this, I did a little test using code I have used before.  It essentially performs the exact same process as what I want from the bootstrap code, and works flawlessly.  Basically I added a regular submit button underneath the bootstrap class button and added some "onclick" JS to it and two new JS functions.  It **stays disabled** AND shows my "working..." text until the page redirects to the thank-you page.  If this works with a regular button, then something is different in the Bootstrap structure that causes it to freak out when a submit occurs.

The javascript code to make this happen is as follows:

```
//--- Disables the submit button (to prevent double clicking) ---
function J_try_submit($disableField, $theAction) {
    document.getElementById($disableField).disabled = true;
    document.jkform.action.value = $theAction;
    document.jkform.submit();
}
//--- Show "Please wait" message ---
function showWait() {
    document.getElementById('waitMsg').style.display = 'block';
}
```

And the code in the HTML is the following:

```
<input id='mySubmit1' type='submit' name='dummy' value='Save Changes' onclick="J_try_submit('mySubmit1','add'); showWait();" />
<div id='waitMsg' style='display: none;font-size:12px;color:#3f7799'>&nbsp;Please wait...</div>
```

Works great and is easy to test.

FINAL NOTE: I do see the disabled cursor when I mouse over the bootstrap button after I click it while it is working, just not the style changes?  So it must actually be disabled, but does not look disabled.  Weird.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: I've never used fiddle, but may need to learn it.  Sounds like a good place to "fiddle" with weird code issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear from this code example, but my guess is you are submitting the form and causing a screen refresh, thus immediately reloading the page. In other words, the JS is executing properly but immediately being overwritten.

If you are building in client side validation and emailing the form from the client, then instead of having your logic attached to a click event on the button, you should attach the logic to a submit event on the form, and call preventDefault in the event callback to prevent the browser's default form handling. For documentation and examples in jQuery, see [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) documentation.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but since the refresh does not call the main form again, and simply goes to a different PHP function that starts generating the email (which can sometimes take a while) I would think the changes to the form button should still be active on-screen.

Comment: It might be helpful if you post all of your code. PHP only runs on the server, Javascript/jQuery is executing in the browser. The only way it "goes to a different PHP function" is if there is a new request being sent to the server from the browser. If it is an AJAX request the browser would not refresh, but you are not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

after submitting your page is reloaded ? if so, the button is not pressed in , the jquery reset. you need to add to the form field `<input type = "hidden" name = "btn-state" value = " 0 " >` . then when you click through to install jquery in the value status and transmit it when the form is submitted . Further php check this box via `$ _GET [btn-value]` and depending on the state ( 0 or 1 ) to set the button text and add class `"btn-disabled"` in php

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem a need to use js here at all, unless you are using it to validate the form input. From what I can gather you are posting the form to itself and validating in php, so you can use the default form submitting behaviour.

Use something like this:

```html
<form id ="jkform" action = "example.com/thispage" method = "post">

 // bunch of forms fields


  //--- Submit Button ---
  <div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9'>
      <button type='button' id='sendButton' class='btn btn primary'>Send</button>";
    </div>";
  </div>
</form>
```

You seem to be adding the `F_hidden_field()` function to the form which is not needed as you can add that as the action and method on the form itself.

This way you can eliminate all the js and extra echo's everywhere in the php. If you need to generate a lot of things in php you can look into template engines such as handlebars which will make things much cleaner and simpler.

If your only intention is to have the effect of the button changing when clicked you could use jquery submit function.